# Prove limit of $f(x) = x^2\cdot sin(1/x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}{x^2 \cdot sin(\frac{1}{x})} = 0$

My  attempt with epsion-delta:
Let $ϵ > 0$ and $δ = \sqrt{ϵ}$
$|f(x)-0| = |x^2 \cdot sin(\frac{1}{x})| \leq |x^2| = |x| \cdot |x| \leq δ \cdot δ = \sqrt{ϵ} \cdot \sqrt{ϵ} = ϵ$
is my prove correct or is my δ-choice invalid?

Comment: It is correct..

Comment: Use `$\epsilon$` for $\epsilon$ and `$\delta$` for $\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine. If you don't feel like using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ directly, it might be even simpler to use the squeeze theorem: $-x^2\leq x^2\sin(1/x)\leq x^2$ for $x\neq 0$, and since $\lim_{x\to 0} \pm x^2 = 0$, we have $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\sin(1/x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer seems fine to me.